# Can I instrument an exe file using vsinstr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

I've been trying to verify the code coverage of an exe file. To achieve this, I'm trying to instrument the exe file (not dll) and then start/stop the coverage.
Every tutorial describes about the instrumentation of dll only. Is it possible to achieve it for exe? If yes, what are the special options I need to give.

Here are the commands, I've been trying for exe:

```
vsinstr -coverage Test.exe
```

Returns success message and creates another copy of exe

```
vsperfcmd -start:coverage -output:Result.coverage

vsperfcmd -shutdown
```

It creates the output file successfully. But when the file opened in visual studio shows the error message:
"Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings."

Please help

Comment: For an alternative to binary instrumentation, see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19827/microsoft-c-code-coverage-software/19828#19828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command starts the profiler service and your second one shuts it down (and causes it to write its output).  What you're missing is the `-attach` command.

```
vsperfcmd -attach:PID
```

where PID is your process's numerical ID.

Once you're attached to a process, it will start collecting coverage data.  Do whatever you need to exercise your code, then run the `shutdown` command to get your output.